How to understand that a $2$-twisted Möbius bundle is trivial and isomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{R}$?
Define the “$2$-twisted Möbius bundle” as the rank-$1$ subbundle $D$ of $E = \mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{R}^2$ defined:

$D_{\mathrm{e}^{\theta \mathrm{i}}} = \operatorname{span}\{\cos(\theta) e_1 + \sin(\theta) e_2\}$.

Or geometrical-equivalently, the analogous of this parametric surface:

$f(\theta, r) = (5 \cos \theta + r \cos^2 \theta, 5 \sin \theta + r \cos \theta \sin \theta, r \sin \theta)$ where $\theta \in [0, 2 \pi], r \in (-1, 1)$.


I can tell by calculation, that this bundle is trivial, and it is (bundle) isomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{R}$.
But it seems very counter-intuitive to me that this bundle is in any sense “trivial”. It is obviously “twisted”, just like the Möbius bundle, $2$ times, then pasted end-to-end. I cannot see any possibility to transform the bundle into $\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{R}$ through a smooth deformation. I know isotopy is a different concept compared to diffeomorphic, but it’s still kind of hard to understand.
I know the knots, the embedded $\mathbb{S}^1$’s in $\mathbb{R}^3$, have rich structures when considering ambient isotopy equivalence. But if we allow the knots to intersect itself when deformation, all knots are equivalent to the unknot. But this seems not the case here, even if we allow self-intersecting, it seems the bundle cannot deform into $\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{R}$? Or I’m wrong about this?
When we are talking about trivial bundles, what exactly are we talking about?

You seem to be confused by the embedding you chose. Being isomorphic to the trivial bundle is independent of embedding, and you should have no trouble finding a section of this double twisted bundle by looking at a different construction, e.g. taking two squares defining the Möbius strip via a quotient on the boundary and pasting them together in suitable ways.

Where does the smoothness fails if you just flip (in $\mathbb{R}^3$) one side–left or right–in your figure?

Remember that a (real) line bundle is trivial if and only if it is orientable.

The reason you're not seeing the transformation and think the bundle is still "twisted" is because this is true in a sense. Namely, the standard embedding $S^1\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ (that is, as an annulus) is not isotopic to the embedding that gives you the doubly twisted Möbius strip $D$. In other words, you cannot continuously deform the doubly twisted Möbius strip $D$ into $S^1\times\mathbb{R}$ within the confines of $\mathbb{R}^3$.
Nonetheless, the two spaces are homeomorphic (and the homeomorphism commutes with the projections to $S^1$, i.e. they are isomorphic bundles). It's possible to write down a parametric formula, but I think it's more important to understand the point geometrically. Imagine cutting up $D$ twice so that it decomposes into a rectangular strip (i.e. a copy of $I\times I$) and a "doubly twisted rectangular strip", which you have to glue along two of their edges to obtain $D$. The doubly twisted rectangular strip is obviously homeomorphic to a standard rectangular strip (you can just un-twist it in $3$-space, so these are even isotopic). The crux now is that this homeomorphism does not change the orientation of the boundary edges, so you can instead just glue two rectangular strips along two equioriented edges, yielding an annulus. Note that if you attempt the same with a regular Möbius strip, the orientations don't match up in the penultimate step, so we don't actually gain anything.
Here is a poor picture by yours truly that hopefully illustrates the point:


Thank you. Now I understand the key here is that, first cut a part, then deform it, and paste it back at the end, the process does not affect the fact that the two objects are homeomorphic. I think this is a great example showing why we can't simply imagine diffeomorphisms as continuous deformations.
